# Ruby on Rails. How to combine a search form with bootstrap style?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

How to combine this search form

```
<%= form_tag index_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "search", :title => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

with this bootstrap style

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any class you like to any Rails form tag.  You just need to be careful that your method call matches one of the valid call signatures for the tag helper.  For instance, the API for the form tag is documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html).

Here is my take on combining the above.  This may need some tuning:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_tag index_path, :method => 'get', class: 'input-group'  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search for...' %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag "search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, working great, but the submit_tag looks like cutting button (not enough button area for "search" word ) you write about some tuning, does you have any fix?

Comment: You could try removing the span.